# c++ templates check value

Tags: c++, templates

I need to write 2 function templates that I don't know how to handle.

First one is a function that returns true only if the function parameter is 100 (I assume int that is equal to 100) but the result should be known during compilation (without RTTI).

EDIT: I don't know the syntax. I think it should be done similar to this: http://blog.emptycrate.com/node/271

And the second one is function that returns true if the parameter is const object or temporary object. (Same conditions as above).

I tried

```
template<class T>
bool isConst(T a) {
    return false;
}

template<class T>
bool const& isConst(T const& a) {
    return true;
}
```

but it doesn't work like intended

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone help me with that?

Yes. Since this is obviously homework, I'll give you a clue instead of giving you the answer, because giving you the answer wouldn't teach you anything.

> First one is a function that returns true only if the function parameter is 100 (I assume int that is equal to 100) but the result should be known during compilation (without RTTI).

0 is false, and anything that is not 0 is true, is that right? Knowing this, you can return an *arithmetic expression* that will represent true or false.

Comment: Not helpfull at all. The result has to be known during compilation. Meaning: I have to write a template that can fire up only if argument is 100 and other template when it is not.